Constructible subsets of an ordinal - an alternate definition?
Work over ZFC. Recall the standard definition of $\mathrm{Def}(X)$, the set of constructible subsets of the set $X$. This can be considered as taking all those subsets of $X$ that satisfy some first-order formula of set theory with parameters $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in X$. In principle, as far as I can tell, this could allow formulas like $\exists y \exists z,\ y\in z \wedge z\in x \ldots $, where $x\in X$ is some given element.
However, if the set $X$ is an ordinal $\alpha$, then it seems to me that because of transitivity and heredity we might in fact be able to rewrite any statement that involves $\in$ to a statement that uses $<$ instead, with the understanding that we were going to be restricting $\in$ to the transitive closure of $\alpha$ in the first place, hence only need to talk about ordinals that are at most $\alpha$. What I'm hoping is 1) I guess there is a well-ordering on $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$ arising from the well-ordering on $\alpha$, using an approach similar to the construction of the well-ordering on $L_{\alpha+1}$ from that on $L_\alpha$, and 2) this well-ordering could in fact be defined via consideration of the order structure and the syntactic structure of the sentences defining subsets (in the above sense), leaving aside the language of set theory (i.e. the $\in$-predicate). In this way, I hope there is a way to sensibly define a class function $\mathrm{Ord} \to \mathrm{Ord}$ that takes an ordinal $\alpha$ and returns the ordinal order-isomorphic to $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$.
I'm slightly wary, because the stages of the constructible and cumulative hierarchies are also transitive sets, and no one that I've seen has made a similar simplification. But, of course, stages aren't usually ordinals! So if $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$ can be defined by suitable rewriting involving $<$ instead of $\in$, then it presumably has to use the hereditary and the transitive nature.
Question: Can $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$ be defined in a way that uses the ordering predicate instead of the membership predicate, for any given ordinal $\alpha$?

If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then $<$ and $\in$ are the same binary relation on $\alpha$. Also, $\alpha$ is already transitive (it is equal to its own transitive closure). So isn't the rewriting you're talking about just using the symbol $<$ in place of $\in$ in all formulas?

@AlexKruckman I'm not a set theorist, I don't know! Also, fiddly things like "first order formula in the language of set theory", but actually via careful Gödel-style encoding as in the notes at the link, are not obviously the same as "first order formula in the theory of a total order", at least to me. I do know $\alpha$ is transitive!

You can certainly define $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$ using formulas in the language of order, simply because $<$ and $\in$ are literally the same binary relation on the ordinal $\alpha$ (and the Gödel coding doesn't "see" what relation symbol you're using!). And you can also define a class function mapping $\alpha$ to the well-order type of $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$, as you hoped. But note that $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$ is no longer an ordinal, so there's no reason to expect that you could similarly characterize $\mathrm{Def}(\mathrm{Def}(\alpha))$ in terms of formulas in the language of order.

@AlexKruckman 1. Excellent and 2. I'm no so fussed about $\mathrm{Def}(\alpha)$ not being an ordinal, because what I want is the ordinal corresponding to it (actually I'd rather not have von Neumann ordinals at all, just well-orders, and this modified version of $\mathrm{Def}$, using only $<$.)

Ok, I'm glad it worked out! Can I ask what the motivation is? Why do you want this function from ordinals to ordinals? (Or from well-orders to well-orders?)

I want to be able to define the power set of an ordinal in L, and from the case the ordinal is the order type of $\alpha\times \beta$, carve out the subset of functions  $\alpha \to \beta$ in L, by only using the well-ordering structure, not the fact we are working with ZF-sets. Getting the function Ord->Ord is a cherry on top.

Ok, I see. But note that $\mathcal{P}^L(X)=\mathcal{P}(X)\cap L \neq\mathrm{Def}(X)$ in general. There will be more subsets of an ordinal $\alpha$ that are definable in $(L_{\alpha+1},\in)$ than just those definable in $(\alpha,\in)$.

To make this clearer: By quantifier elimination in the theory of discrete linear orders, $\mathrm{Def}(\omega)$ contains only the finite and cofinite subsets of $\omega$. Obviously $L$ contains a much richer collection of subsets of $\omega$.

Hmm. Will have to think about this one. Thanks for the sanity check!

Summarizing my comments by an answer:
Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal. Then we can certainly consider the set $\DeclareMathOperator{\Def}{Def}\Def_<(\alpha)$ of all subsets of the structure $(\alpha,<)$ definable by a first-order formula with parameters in the language of order.
Moreover, since $<$ and $\in$ are the same binary relation on $\alpha$, a subset of $\alpha$ is definable by a formula in the language of order if and only if it is definable in the language of set theory (by the same formula, with the symbol $<$ replaced by the symbol $\in$). So $\Def_<(\alpha)$ as defined above agrees with the operation $\Def(x)$ used in the definition of the constructible universe $L$.
However, for a set $X\in L$, $\mathcal{P}^L(X) = \mathcal{P}(X)\cap L\neq \Def(X)$ in general. If $X\in L_\alpha$ there will typically be more subsets of $X$ in $\Def(L_\alpha)$ than there are in $\Def(X)$ (since the formulas used in defining $\Def(L_\alpha)$ can quantify over all the elements of $L_\alpha$, while the formulas used in defining $\Def(X)$ can only quantify over the elements of $X$).
For example, by quantifier elimination in the theory of discrete linear orders (in a suitably expanded language), $\Def(\omega)$ consists of the finite and cofinite subsets of $\omega$. Obviously $L$ contains a much richer collection of subsets of $\omega$.
So for an ordinal $\alpha$, while we can construct $\Def(\alpha) = \Def_<(\alpha)$ making reference only to the order on $\alpha$, this fails to give a description of the powerset of $\alpha$ in $L$. Whenever $\alpha$ is infinite, there will be subsets of $\alpha$ in $\mathcal{P}^L(\alpha)$ which are not definable purely from the order on $\alpha$.
